# Would updating my rooted Sony Xperia Z brick it?

Tags: root-access, unrooting, sony-xperia-z

I updated my phone, rooted it and then realized the current version isn't the latest, so I would like to update it. Is there any chance my Xperia Z would brick? Or do I have to unroot it first?

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery? There is a chance it won't allow you to install it with a custom recovery, you'd need the stock one. You will lose root possibly but can re-root anyway.

Comment: @RossC No I don't have a custom recovery. By the way, I'm using custom fonts so when my root is lost after the installation, the font will be using the default font, right

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. It most likely will install the stock font, but I'd need someone more knowledgeable to confirm that. I guess it depends on what's included in the OTA update.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Instead you may lose your root access in turn, because some system settings go back to default when updating a device, which will probably include your superuser.

Your personal data and installed apps will not be affected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How high are the chances of losing root access? Also, my personal data won't be affected, right?

Comment: Very. And [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/192402/why-androids-ota-updates-remove-root-and-how-to-keep-it/) is the reason why.